# If there are many groups specified in TestNG xml, how do I run only a specific group/groups?I dont have maven or ant.I have testng xml and code

Tags: testng

If there are many groups specified in TestNG xml, how do I run only a specific group/groups?I don't have maven or ant.I have testng xml and code.

Answer (score 0):

Make a copy of your TestNG.xml, say %GROUP_NAME%.xml, with specific group/groups and run it instead. You can have as many declared TestNG documents as you want.